# HSQLDB In-memory database JDBC Template Query failing

Tags: java, hsqldb, jdbctemplate

I have a unit test, that uses JDBCTemplate and an in-memory database. My HSQLDB Settings are :

```
jdbc.driver.className=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:mem\:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY\=-1
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
```

I am creating a table and then trying to check if any data exists in it through JDBCTemplate before inserting a new record in it.

I am invoking JDBC query through JDBCTemplate as below:

```
String query = "select id from Person where id=?";
int isExist = jdbcTemplate.update(query, "1");
```

In my config xml, I have wired the dataSource as below:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" lazy-init="default" autowire="default">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver.className}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I am getting an error that says :

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException : statement does not generate a row count
```

The same code works if i remove in memory database and actually connect to an Oracle Database but for tests I need in memory database.

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you post some code it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Why do you use the method `jdbcTemplate.update()`? I think you should use a `query`, `execute` or similar ... for example `queryForInt` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `JdbcTemplate.query` method, the `update` method is for insert/delete/update statements. For example:

```
int isExist = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(query, "1");
```

Comment: I am getting the same exception when tried to call stored procedures using jdbcTemplate.query().